# How to fix compile proto file?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Good day. For the development needed gRPC. The .proto file itself is written and needs to be compiled for python. And here there were questions, since I could not compile.
That's what I did.
With git, I downloaded the latest protobuf (3.9.0). And then I took such steps:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo protoc -I=/home/vlad/protobuf-3.9.0 --python_out=/home/vlad/protobuf-3.9.0/ /home/vlad/protobuf-3.9.0/grpc-adpt.proto
```

In total, only the file appeared * pb2.py
And grpc-adpt.proto: 3: 1 fell out in the console: warning: Import google / protobuf / wrappers.proto but not used.
And accordingly bp2_grpc.py was not created
Also did as written in the ReadMe

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py test
cd /home/vlad/protobuf-3.9.0
make
```

Further as

```
sudo protoc -I=/home/vlad/protobuf-3.9.0 --python_out=/home/vlad/protobuf-3.9.0/ /home/vlad/protobuf-3.9.0/grpc-adpt.proto
```

And the same mistake
grpc-adpt.proto: 3: 1: warning: Import google / protobuf / wrappers.proto but not used.
Start code

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";``
```

Comment: a warning is exactly that: just a warning - it shouldn't stop the output, but if you want to remove the warning: remove the `import` for wrappers.proto (the first one), since it isn't needed. I don't expect that to change the behaviour, though; you haven't shown us anything useful about the contents of `grpc-adpt.proto`, so I can't predict what files I *expect* it to generate. Can you give us more context as to what you expected to happen, and why? You mention `bp2.py`, but we don't know *anything* about `bp2.proto` (if it even exists). We *need more detail here*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was a problem with the packages .protoc. On another computer compiled